# AWS OpenVPN Server Failure Protection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openvpn

I've setup and configured OpenVpn on an AWS EC2 instance running in a ASG with an elastic IP

So, if the EC2 goes down for any reason. The ASG will bring one back up

But the new one that comes up won't have the configuration changes and the users I added on the OpenVpn server

How do I make sure that the configurations and users are carried over ?

Current Solution in mind : Create an Image with the settings and use that AMI to create the Server

Issues : Maintaining and installing security updates to this server will become an issue

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem, which was resolved by using EFS. With EFS you can share the folder with all added users/certificates accross multiple servers without any problem.  You need to activate EFS for your VPC and create a mount point in each of the EC2 instance filesystem - you can use EC2 userdata to mount it while launching. Do not forget about right security groups that is required by EFS as otherwise it will not be accessible within the VPC.